How to initialize complex matrices in gradient descent?
I have four equations. Edit:

$(e + i \bar{e}) = ( m + i \bar{m} ) - (y + i \bar{y})  $,
$(y + i \bar{y})  = (W_3 + i \bar{W_3} ) (h + i \bar{h})  $
$(h + i \bar{h}) = (z + i \bar{z}) + (W_2 + i\bar{W_2}) (z + i \bar{z}) + (f + i \bar{f}) $
$(f + i \bar{f}) = W_1 * (x + i \bar{x}) $

All variables and matrices can have complex-valued entries except $W_1$, which should be real. Dimensions are: $W_1$ is 100x1, $W_2$ is 100x100, $W_3$ is 1x100;
I need to update matrices $W_1$, $W_2$, and $W_3$ using gradient descent to minimize the cost function: $J = e^H e$. Note that although the cost function is real-valued, it is a function of complex variables and matrices.
Edit:
(I have this running in Matlab). Maybe I got the gradients wrong? Could anyone please help?
The gradients I obtained are in the attached figure.



Is $e^T$ the conjugate transpose?

A gradient with respect to a complex variable does not make sense.

@CyclotomicField , T is for transpose. I edited to make notation clearer

@copper.hat There are several applications with gradient descent in complex networks. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479024/how-tensorflow-handles-complex-gradient and http://dsp.ucsd.edu/~kreutz/PEI-05%20Support%20Files/complex_derivatives.pdf

@copper.hat is correct.  Optimization with gradient descent is developed for inner product spaces over the reals.  You need to alter your problem so that this is what you’re doing.  E.g., <x,y> = real( x . y )

@user3284182 If $e^T$ is just the transpose then it's impossible to minimize $J=e^Te$ since it's a complex number. Note that if $e$ is real valued then $e^Te=|e|^2$ and if $e$ is complex (or real) valued then the conjugate transpose $e^*$ gives $e^*e=|e|^2$. So it's typically what's used in this sort of problem and I would double check it.

@CyclotomicField Please see edition..J = e^H e.. but it seems that the gradients are not right because the implementation is exploding

@user3284182 your code should work once you fix the transpose/conjugate transpose problem. All your errors should be real numbers now.

Technically, is this not 4 questions? Or problems I guess, but I think you get my point.

Converting the $\sf Complex$ variables into $\sf Real$ block matrices
$$\eqalign{
\def\w{\widehat}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\frob#1{\big| #1 \big|_F^2}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r|r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\LR{A+iB};; &\quad\sim\quad; \w A=\m{A&-B\\hline B&A} \
\LR{E+iF} + \LR{A+iB};; &\quad\sim\quad; \w E+\w A \
\LR{M+iN}:\LR{A+iB};; &\quad\sim\quad; \w M\w A \
2,\frob{A+iB} &\quad=\quad; \frob{\w A} \
}$$
avoids any issues with complex arithmetic (but doubles  memory usage).

@greg Good point. I have separated everything in real and imaginary parts. The gradients I obtained are in the new post edit, although  I did not use the block matrix approach. I coded this and the cost function reduces between some epochs and then just explodes. Maybe I got some gradient wrong?
